# Looking to find out how to call this javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I understand that Z and A are the functions that are being called in this minified code below.

```
function (A){z(a(l.username.el),"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.']+$","username")}
```

My question is how would I call this function using

```
Navigate Url=javascript:(somecode)
```

Can someone please give me an example of how I would call this function by Url= its a username field that turns green after the user enters their username for a javascript form.

Answer (score 2):

It is a function expression which (in the code you've provided with us) is never called or assigned anywhere, so you can't.

The code (like any code which has no side effects and isn't assigned anywhere) effectively does nothing.

> I understand that Z and A are the functions

No.

`Z` doesn't exist. `A` is an argument which is never used. `z` and `a` are functions it calls.

You could call those functions yourself (by extracting the body of the function expression) if they appeared in the global scope.

Comment: technically it is no function expression but plain wrong. It will throw an syntax error as it stands.

Comment: ahh i see I used the chrome plugin Visual event and this what it showed me was bound to that username field I cant seem to find what function to call to trigger the green box after the username has been filled.

Comment: @Christoph — True, it would have to be used in the right context.

Comment: He can "call" it like that: `(function (A){z(a(l.username.el),"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.']+$","username")}
)('the data passed as A');` if `a` and `z` are defined :)

Comment: So what could i provide that would help in figuring out what to call by the url to turn the box green?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call this function, because it's anonymous...

if you want to call it you need to do:

```
var test = function (A){z(a(l.username.el),"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.']+$","username")};
var result = test('sample');
```

If you want to call an anonymous function:

```
var result = (function (A){z(a(l.username.el),"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.']+$","username")})('sample');
```